# Modify the DOM in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I developed a mobile application with Ionic. I have a controller that recovers a series of posts on a server and returns the data in JSON, which contains the following properties:

```
[{
  "kick_id":"5",
  "author_id":"2",
  "content":"Contenue de la publication",
  "kick_at":"2016-08-12 19:04:58",
  "user_id":"2",
  "pseudo_name":"xxxxx-x",
  "nb_likes":"1",
  "nb_dislikes":"0",
  "isLike":true,
  "isDislike":false
}]
```

In my view, I use the properties "isLike" and "isDislike" to determine if the user has liked or disliked the publication in question. I apply a condition on these two fields to add "LIKE1" class, if the user liked and "like-1" if he disliked:

```
<footer class="kick-foot padding">
    <div class="kick-footer-btn" ng-class="{'like1': kick.isLike == true}" ng-click="like({{kick.kick_id}})" value="true" ng-model="kick.isLike">
        <span class="label-ico">Pro {{kick.nb_likes}}</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

My system works but at present I encounter a difficulty add class dynamically as the user likes (like) or dislike a new publication. I do not know how to do. please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you mean exactly but If you want to change class dynamically you should do this:

```
ng-class="{'like1': kick.isLike, 'dislike1': kick.isDislike}"
```